# Is there a noncommutative version of von Neumann's ergodic theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-algebras, ergodic-theory, von-neumann-algebras

The two most celebrated ergodic theorems are Birkhoff's ergodic theorem and von Neumann's ergodic theorem.

E. C. Lance in his remarkable work (*Ergodic Theorems for Convex Sets and Operator Algebras*) formulated that can be considered to be the noncommutative version of Birkhoff's ergodic theorem, for a von Neumann algebra, $T*$-automorphism and a faithful $T$-invariant normal state.

I would like to know whether someone has done the same for von Neumann's ergodic theorem. In other words, is there a noncommutative version of von Neumann's ergodic theorem ?

Comment: I think it is more likely that you receive answers if you post this question in mathoverflow.

Comment: On MO at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334592/is-there-a-noncommutative-version-of-von-neumanns-ergodic-theorem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, and non-commutative ergodic theory is a big chunk of the industry of von Neumann algebras these days. Perhaps the starting point should be this paper by Yeadon:

- F. J. Yeadon, [Ergodic Theorems for Semifinite Von Neumann Algebras—I](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s2-16/2/326/1012284?redirectedFrom=PDF), *Journal of the London Mathematical Society*, **s2-16**, Issue 2 (1977), 326–332.

It gives you exactly what you seek. [Part II of the paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/ergodic-theorems-for-semifinite-von-neumann-algebras-ii/55AC4AAA614E55C9651F7617A4179020) as well as papers citing it is something you may be interested in.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am gonna take a look at the mentioned articles.